# How may you call an object that is used for something other than its intended purpose?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If I was to use or misuse an object that is intended to fulfil a certain purpose for another purpose. For example the purpose of a chair is to sit on. But I can stand on it too. Of course it remains to be chair. According to the answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145852/what-is-the-word-for-using-something-for-other-than-its-intended-purpose), the act of using it for another is called exaptation.

I expect there to be a word for any object that is used for another purpose. Any ideas? I'm thinking in the direction of a *placeholder*.

I feel that the word *off-label* that has been given as an answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245862/a-term-for-products-whose-secret-features-are-well-known-but-not-publicized) is not suitable to use for that chair while I stand on it.

Comment: I think there has to be a simpler but better answer than the one given to the question that is *not* a duplicate to me. I will not call that chair *off-label* while I stand on it

Comment: The word I  would use does not appear in the answers to the "duplicate" question - in fact, it was in another question that was closed.  A correct answer is:  "I used the chair as an ERSATZ ladder."  (Sorry, I  don't know how to 'bold' or italicize for emphasis in the comment section.)

Comment: Thanks. You helped me in the right direction. I may also call that chair a *mock* I guess. (To bold prefix and suffix the word with ** and for italic * It's called markdown)

Comment: When a medicine turns out to be useful for some other purpose than the one it was tested for, that's called an "off-label use".